# Issue with running $.ajax in IE and firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-dialog

Hey guys I am using chrome and developed a window opener using the JQuery UI and it works perfect.  In IE and Firefox I notice it wont work and I did the debugging in IE and it said

```
 `SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number`

function sendUserfNotes()
    {

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/pcg/popups/getNotes.php',
        data:
        {
            'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),

        },<!-- gave me the error right here?

        success: function(response) {
            $('#notes_msg').text(response.the_notes);
        }
    });
```

No idea why but here is my scripts:

```
$(document).ready(function () { // this right here will wait to see if the 'access notes is clicked, if so then it will get te value of username and send it to run()
    $(".NotesAccessor").click(function () {
        notes_name = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_table");

      run();
    });

    });
function run(){ // defines the place to get the notes, goes to showURL...() to open the JQuery dialog and than senduse....() to display them in the dialog.  
    var url = '/pcg/popups/grabnotes.php';

    showUrlInDialog(url);
    sendUserfNotes();


}
    function showUrlInDialog(url)
    {
      var tag = $("#dialog-container");
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
          tag.html(data).dialog
          ({
              width: '100%',
                modal: true
          }).dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }
    function sendUserfNotes()
    {

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/pcg/popups/getNotes.php',
        data:
        {
            'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),

        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#notes_msg').text(response.the_notes);
        }
    });

    }
    function getNewnotes(){
        new_notes = $('#notes_msg').val();
        update(new_notes);  
    }
    // if user updates notes
    function update(new_notes)
    {

            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //dataType: "json",
        url: '/pcg/popups/updateNotes.php',
        data:
        {
            'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),
            'newNotes': new_notes,  
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Notes Updated.");
            var i;
             $("#dialog-container").effect( 'fade', 500 );

            i = setInterval(function(){
             $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
            clearInterval(i);
            }, 500);

            }
    });

    }
    /******is user closes notes ******/
    function closeNotes()
    {
        var i;
         $("#dialog-container").effect( 'fade', 500 );

        i = setInterval(function(){
         $("#dialog-container").dialog( 'close' );
        clearInterval(i);
        }, 500);

    }
```

If you could give me a hand I would appreciate it :)  Not to sure whats wrong and why it will only work in Chrome?  Let me know if you need anything.

David

Comment: The error it gave you is actually right here `'nameNotes': notes_name.text(), <_--`. Trailing commas are historic for breaking IE. I don't know about FF though....

Comment: What error do you get in Firefox?

Comment: Your right that worked for IE, what about FF?

Comment: Can't tell I don't have the debugger for it...all I know is nothing happens.

Comment: Use Firebug or just open the console.

Comment: @james246 I got rid of it.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I didn't get anything in the console for the Firebug..

Comment: Why do you use `setInterval` that way (to only let it fire once)? You know about `setTimeout`, don't you?

Comment: @Marcel here enter chat I actually got an error in Firebug....and I know I didn't realize at the time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24288/discussion-between-david-biga-and-marcel-korpel)

Answer (score 0):

`data:
{
  'nameNotes': notes_name.text(),
},`

It's a weird issue but remove comma after `text()`. That should helps.